# How to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 SSIS package to SQL server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

We have few SSIS packages developed using VS 2008 R2 business development studio.  WE need to upgrade them to SQL Server 2016.  But I don't see a download for SQL Server 2016 business development studio.  The only SQL Server Data tools available are for 2017(Preview) & 2015.  Please let me know, how to upgrade these packages?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Thanks in advance.

Edit:  I tried to open with VS2015.  I do have SSDT installed as per this screenshot.
[image]

Comment: `SQL Server Data tools available are for 2017(Preview) & 2015` => **It is Visual Studio versions** not SQL Server version, download 2015, open project in Visual Studio and deploy

Comment: I already have Visual Studio 2015.  Do you mean download SQL Server data tools for 2015?

Comment: Exactly. Download, install and run

Comment: Thank you.  Can I deploy the packages to SQL Server 2016 when I open in 2015 version of BDS?

Comment: Yes, it should work. Please forgot the Business Developemnt Studio name, nowadays there is Visual Studio + SSDT.

Comment: @WinFXGuy look at my answer , i provided a table from  Microsoft article showing the related version of visual studio related to each SQL server version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side), these are the related visual studio versions related to SQL Server :

```
==================================================================================================================================================
|| SQL Server version  ||   Development environment for SSIS packages                                                                           ||
==================================================================================================================================================
|| 2016                ||  SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015                                                                         ||
|| 2014                ||  SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 ||
|| 2012                ||  SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 ||
|| 2008                ||  Business Intelligence Development Studio from SQL Server 2008                                                        ||
|| 2005                ||  Business Intelligence Development Studio from SQL Server 2005                                                        ||
==================================================================================================================================================
```

To upgrade package, all you need is to download SQL Server data tools 2015, and open the package with it. It will upgrade it automatically

**Related Articles:**

- [Upgrade Integration Services Packages Using the SSIS Package Upgrade Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services-packages-using-the-ssis-package-upgrade-wizard)
- [Upgrade Integration Services Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services-packages)
- [UPGRADE 2005/2008 SSIS PACKAGES TO 2012 LIKE A BOSS!](https://sqldusty.com/2012/03/19/upgrade-2008-ssis-packages-to-2012-like-a-boss/)

Comment: I opened with VS2015, but I am getting the error. "The project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: @WinFXGuy i added some links to my answers. take a look